# count maximum occurrence of a value per customer

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, data-manipulation

I have a dataset for a helpdesk system I am building a report for and I need to be able to count the maximum contact attempt for each customer.  A customer can have multiple tickets open at any given time.

This is the code I am presently using

```
  select *
  from reporting
  order by Job_id, seq_id, REason
```

```
SEQ_ID  job_id      EVENT_Name      reason                     account_number    
1       70449       Created                                     10341307
2       70449       Available                                   10341307
3       70449       Allocated                                   10341307
4       70449       Rescheduled     Failed Contact - Attempt 1  10341307
```

Above is example output.

The Failed Contact Attempt can occur up to three times with the Attempt number increasing each time. So if a customer has a Failed Contact - Attempt 3 I only want to count that attempt, nothing that proceeds it.

How canI do this?

Comment: What are the results that you want?  Are you trying to eliminate only failed contacts or *everything* before the contacts?

Comment: Basically what I am after is anything that is Failed Contact Attempt or anything, which has been Allocated that doesn't have a Failed Contact Attempt and count them.  But when it comes to Failed Contact Attempt I only the most recent one needs to be counted.  This will show how many tickets are currently open.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep only the most recent "failed contact" (if any) then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when reason like 'Failed Contact%' then 1 else 2 end)
                                order by seq_id desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from reporting r
     ) r
where seqnum = 1 or reason not like 'Failed Contact%'
order by Job_id, seq_id, Reason;
```